# Will Azure Cloud Service in Suspended state with Stopped Web role incur cost?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

When the Azure Cloud Service is suspended and the Web Role associated with it has status Stopped VM, will this Cloud Service incur VM costs?

If not, how can I stop the Cloud Service so it will not incur cost but can be easily started when needed?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I looked into the wrong thing previously. This link may help:

[Does Azure Worker Roles get charged $$ when they are Sleeping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050669/does-azure-worker-roles-get-charged-when-they-are-sleeping)

Either way: The short answer is yes. Everything I searched for within SO or Google says that you will still be charged. The only recommendation was to delete.

Azure web site offers a free online chatting tool that allows you to talk to Microsoft directly to know for 100%. If you do that route, then please come back and let us know for future users.

**Original** (may be useful for future)
I had recently asked Azure the same question. They recommended that I should either stop the server when not in use or move it to a free tier. They also said if the data is still on the VM or Web App, I will still be charged for that.

Your VM says Stopped rather than Stopped (Deallocated) so it may still cost you.

This link may help: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2015/04/22/difference-between-the-states-of-azure-virtual-machines-stopped-and-stopped-deallocated/

Try moving it to the free tier.

In addtion to here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/app-service/linux/

It says:

> Am I charged for apps while they are in stopped state? Yes. Rates
>   listed apply to apps in stopped state. Please delete apps that are not
>   in use, or update the tier to Free to avoid charges.

Comment: Sorry for the extra edits. I was chatting to the Azure Online Support to confirm.

Comment: Liam the question is about Cloud Service while your answer is about App Service :).

Comment: In that case, this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050669/does-azure-worker-roles-get-charged-when-they-are-sleeping